# Inverse fourier transform of exponentially decaying function in the frequency domain

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I want to take the inverse Fourier transform of the following function:

$$ \hat{f}(\omega) = \begin{cases}e^{-r  \sqrt{\omega}} & \text{for } \omega > 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$

such that

$$ f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(w)e^{i\omega t} d\omega= \int_0^\infty e^{-r \sqrt{\omega}} e^{i\omega t} d\omega,$$

where $r$ is a constant.

I am having trouble in integrating this. That $ \sqrt{\omega}$ is ruining my day. Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Comment: I added a hat to one of the $f$. Your $\hat{f}$ is not defined for negative $\omega$, so the problem is incorrectly stated. Could you please check with your source, and fix your question if necessary?

Comment: Thank you for the remark. There is really no source for this problem, this is just me being curious. The function should be $f(\omega) = e^{-r \sqrt{\omega}}$ for $\omega \geq 0$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: It's unusual (sounds almost wrong, though of course it's not wrong per se) to have a real Fourier transform, and a complex "signal". It would be more natural to state it as if the original is the signal ($t$ instead of $w$), and ask instead of the Fourier transform of $f(t)=\exp (-r \sqrt{t})$, $t>0$

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $\omega = u^2$ and consider the resulting expression as

$$-2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{-r u} \, e^{i t u^2}$$

The integral will end up being some sort of error function of complex argument; the derivative may invoke a more elementary expression, but likely not.

Answer (score 2):

This would amount to compute the [Fourier transform of a streched exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_exponential_function#Fourier_Transform), which has no simple-closed form formula, it's known as the [Kohlrausch–Williams–Watts function](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/5/4/604/pdf). See also [here](http://journal.austms.org.au/ojs/index.php/ANZIAMJ/article/download/924/735).